# Apply rotation to rigidbody transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have been working on Roll a ball type game. Where i want to rotate the rigid-body on X-axis and rigid-body transform on Y-axis. I know rigidbody rotation and transform rotation are not good friends. After applying rotation it gives jitter effect.

Please help me how i can fix this issue.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (applyBrakes) { rb.velocity = rb.velocity * 0.85f; return; }
    var localInput = moveHorizontal * cvCam.right +   moveVertical * cvCam.forward;
     var templocal = transform.InverseTransformDirection(localInput).normalized;
    m_TurnAmount =  Mathf.Atan2( templocal.x , templocal.z );
    localInput.y = 0;
    rb.angularVelocity += new Vector3(localInput.z , 0 , -localInput.x) * force * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    print(m_TurnAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 360);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up ,  m_TurnAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 360 , Space.World );        
    if (rb.velocity.magnitude > maxVelocity)
    {
        rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * maxVelocity;
    }
}
```

Need a help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use physics you should not assign or access anything via `Transform` but rather always only go through the `Rigibody`.

Instead of going through `transform.Rotate` you could try and rather use e.g.

```
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * (Quaternion.Inverse(rb.rotation) * Quaternion.Euler(0, m_TurnAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 360, 0) * rb.rotation));
```

replicating the behavior of `Transform.Rotate` for `Space.World` (see [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/0aa4923aa67e701940c22821c137c8d0184159b2/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs#L169))

Comment: this solution is not working for me. I want to roll a ball in forward axis and rotate it to  y-axis only. I have already applied rotation constraint to z-axis in rigidbody settings. The problem is when i rotate the Y-axis using rigidbody moveRotation it moves in z-axis as well.

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/B-OwYKZ60Lo?feature=share sending you a link for better understanding.